# How to change a Chrome App's title bar color programmatically?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I have a packaged Chrome App, for which I am setting the title bar color as follows:

```
chrome.app.window.create("index.html", {
  "id": "app",
  "bounds": {
     width: width,
     height: height
  },
  "frame": {color: "#F44336"},
});
```

The above code is working fine as it is creating the app window with the desired color. Now I would like to change that color through script, as my app features different themes and I need to change the title bar color to match the selected theme.

Is there any way to change the title bar color once the window is loaded?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way to change the title bar color once the window is loaded?

**Interestingly, the answer is "no".**

Everything you can do with a window after creation is accessible through the `AppWindow` object itself returned by `create`; alternatively, you can get a reference to the current `AppWindow` with `chrome.app.window.current()`.

However, [looking at the documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#type-AppWindow), there isn't anything related to the window frame in the object.

Looking at the actual object, there are undocumented properties `hasFrameColor`, `activeFrameColor` and `inactiveFrameColor`, but those are getters-only, you cannot set them.

This may be a decent [feature request](https://crbug.com/new), there doesn't appear to be an existing one.